# Build error debugging an app on android studio created in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72200Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
Error:Content is not allowed in prolog.
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
C:\Users\Akhil Dev\Desktop\New folder\Min-O-Mee3\app\src\main\res\fonts\Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf
Error:Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\Akhil Dev\Desktop\New folder\Min-O-Mee3\app\src\main\res\fonts\Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf:0:0: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 11.136 secs
Information:3 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Please tell me what to do, for no more errors

Answer (score 0):

In the "Build Variants" panel window on the left, you should see both of your modules, and next to them the current "active" variants. For instance

```
app          debug
custom_lib   debug
```

When calling Build > Make Project we are building every modules in the project in their current variant.

However, due to a current Gradle limitation (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962), building app in debug will require building the release variant of custom_lib, and so you end up building both.

I would recommend to not use Make Project but instead use the option below that says Make Module app. This option will change from app to lib based on the current selection in the Project panel or based on the current editor, and will always do only what's needed to build the current module.

(Looking into this, we noticed that there isn't a shortcut for it, so we're adding one).

Comment: I did what you recommended but nothing changed, I need help to resolve these errors in the first place.